# Classification of rings Morita equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I want to classify such rings. I have no idea where to start.

Should I try to somehow see what pro generators in ${}_\mathbb{R}\bf{Mod}$, ${}_\mathbb{Q}\bf{Mod}$, and ${}_\mathbb{Z}\bf{Mod}$ look like?

Comment: For a field, $F$, the only rings Morita equivalent to $F$ are the matrix rings $M_n(F)$.

Comment: why is that true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be a good approach, because it's obvious what the progenerators are.

Every module over a field is free, hence projective. Then the finitely generated ones are exactly $F^n$ for various $n$. The endomorphism rings of these are just $M_n(F)$.

The integers, being a PID, have the property that projective modules are free. So again, the progenerators are of the form $\mathbb Z^n$, and the endomorphism rings are $M_n(\mathbb Z)$.